# EC2 Systems Manager - Install security patches

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, systemmanagement

I am trying to use EC2 Systems Manager with maintenance windows just to apply security patches. I could not find a document that makes this. Does anyone already made this and can provide me a clue?

I know that AWS provide **Patch Manager** for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the official documentation for getting started with patching in EC2 Systems Manager here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/systems-manager-patch.html

There's also a walkthrough that covers the complete set of steps to get started available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/sysman-patch-walkthrough.html

I've added some specific examples related to your questions using the AWS CLI and the AWS Toolkit for PowerShell. You can, of course, also do all of these actions in the AWS Console.

## Installing Security Patches

To control the patches that should be installed, you use a Patch Baseline. The Patch Baseline consists of a set of rules that define which patches should be approved for deployment and when they should be approved along with an optional set of explicitly approved and rejected patches.

### Creating a Patch Baseline

In your case, to apply just security patches, you can create a Patch Baseline like this:

**AWS CLI**

```
aws ssm create-patch-baseline --name "Only-Security-Patches"
  --approval-rules "PatchRules=[{PatchFilterGroup={PatchFilters=[{Key=CLASSIFICATION,Values=SecurityUpdates}]},ApproveAfterDays=3}]" 
  --description "Security updates for all versions of Windows"
```

**AWS PowerShell**

```
$rule = New-Object Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.PatchRule
$rule.ApproveAfterDays = 3
$ruleFilters = New-Object Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.PatchFilterGroup
$classificationFilter = New-Object Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.PatchFilter
$classificationFilter.Key = "CLASSIFICATION"
$classificationFilter.Values.Add( "SecurityUpdates" )
$ruleFilters.PatchFilters.Add($classificationFilter)
$rule.PatchFilterGroup = $ruleFilters
New-SSMPatchBaseline 
  -Name "Only-Security-Patches" `
  -Description "Security updates for all versions of Windows" `
  -ApprovalRules_PatchRule $rule
```

### Defining the Default Patch Baseline

You control which Patch Baseline you want to use for a particular EC2 instance by tagging the instance with the `Patch Group` tag, setting the value of the tag to the name of the patch group of your choice. After that you can register the patch group to the Patch Baseline. For the sake of this example you can also define your new Patch Baseline as the default Patch Baseline to use for all instances that aren't tagged with the `Patch Group` tag:

**AWS CLI**

```
aws ssm register-default-patch-baseline --baseline-id <the id of the patch baseline created above>
```

***AWS PowerShell**

```
Register-SSMDefaultPatchBaseline-BaselineId <the id of the patch baseline created above>
```

## Driving Patching Using a Maintenance Window

Once you have your desired Patch Baseline created and configured, you can use the `AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline` Command document to patch an instance. If you just want to test patching you can use Run Command to send the command to your instance, but if you want to automate it, Maintenance Windows are there to help.

A Maintenance Window defines:

- What instances are valid targets for tasks in the Maintenance Window
- What tasks should be performed on what targets
- When these tasks should be performed

Registering instances as targets with a Maintenance Window is optional and in the examples below I'm choosing to not require target registration.

### Creating a Maintenance Window

For the purposes of this example, let's create a Maintenance Window that runs at 4pm every Tuesday with a 4 hour duration:

**AWS CLI**

```
aws ssm create-maintenance-window 
  --name "My-Tuesday-Maintenance-Window" 
  --schedule "cron(0 16 ? * TUE *)" 
  --duration 4 
  --cutoff 1
  --allow-unassociated-targets
```

***AWS PowerShell**

```
New-SSMMaintenanceWindow `
  -Name "My-Tuesday-Maintenance-Window" `
  -Schedule "cron(0 16 ? * TUE *)" `
  -Duration 4 `
  -Cutoff 1 `
  -AllowUnassociatedTarget $true `
```

### Registering the Patching Task

With the Maintenance Window created, you can now register the tasks you want to run in it, in this case we want to run the `AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline` command.

Please note that the commands below assume that you've performed the steps to define the IAM role (I've named this role *MW-Role* here) you want to use for your Maintenance Windows as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/sysman-patch-walkthrough.html

**AWS CLI**

```
aws ssm register-task-with-maintenance-window 
  --window-id <the id of your maintenance window>
  --targets "Key=InstanceIds,Values=<comma-separated list of instance ids>" 
  --task-arn "AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline" 
  --service-role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<your account id>:role/MW-Role" 
  --task-type "RUN_COMMAND" 
  --max-concurrency 2 
  --max-errors 1 
  --priority 1 
  --task-parameters '{\"Operation\":{\"Values\":[\"Install\"]}}'
```

**AWS PowerShell**

```
$parameters = @{}
$parameterValues = new-object Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.MaintenanceWindowTaskParameterValueExpression
$parameterValues.Values = @("Install")
$parameters.Add("Operation", $parameterValues)

Register-SSMTaskWithMaintenanceWindow `
  -WindowId <the id of your maintenance window> `
  -Target @{ Key="InstanceIds";Values="<comma-separated list of instance ids>" } `
  -TaskArn "AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline" `
  -ServiceRoleArn "arn:aws:iam::<your account id>:role/MW-Role" `
  -TaskType "RUN_COMMAND" `
  -MaxConcurrency 2 `
  -MaxErrors 1 `
  -Priority 1 `
  -TaskParameter $parameters `
```

## Other Interesting Features

Now that everything has been configured you can see the history of Maintenance Window executions and the patch compliance state of the instances being patched.

### Maintenance Window Executions

You can use the following commands to drill down into the execution history for your Maintenance Windows:

**AWS CLI**

- [describe-maintenance-window-executions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-maintenance-window-executions.html)
- [describe-maintenance-window-execution-tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-maintenance-window-execution-tasks.html)
- [describe-maintenance-window-execution-task-invocations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-maintenance-window-execution-task-invocations.html)

**AWS PowerShell**

- [Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionList](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionList.html&tocid=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionList)
- [Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskList](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskList.html&tocid=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskList)
- [Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskInvocationList](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskInvocationList.html&tocid=Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowExecutionTaskInvocationList)

### Patch Compliance Information

Once your instances have been patched you can get patch compliance information for them.

**AWS CLI**

- [describe-instance-patch-states](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-instance-patch-states.html)
- [describe-instance-patches](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-instance-patches.html)

**AWS PowerShell**

- [Get-SSMInstancePatchState](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-SSMInstancePatchState.html&tocid=Get-SSMInstancePatchState)
- [Get-SSMInstancePatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-SSMInstancePatch.html&tocid=Get-SSMInstancePatch)

I hope this helps answer your question, if not please let me know.